# How do you defeat the walkers?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

There are bipedal walkers, how can you defeat them without killing the pilot ?

Should you always sneak from behind and shoot darts ?

Are there more efficient ways to deal with them ?

Comment: So far, I've only shot darts at them. I suppose you could extract them while still in the Walker if you're fast (and silent) enough, like you can regular vehicles. The Walker would need to be standing still, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most stealthy way would be to sneak up behind one and use CQC on the pilot. If you are using the Sneaking Suit, you can even sprint up behind one that is on patrol.